# How does this weird monad bind work?

Tags: list, haskell, return, bind, monads

This is probably a very noob question but I was playing around with the bind operator in Haskell and I encountered a way to repeat a string using it.

```
[1..3] >>= const "Hey"
-- Yields "HeyHeyHey"
[1..3] >>= return "Hey"
-- Also yields the same result
```

I understand how `>>= (\_ -> return "Hey")` would yield `["Hey", "Hey", "Hey"]` but I don't understand why `(\_ -> "Hey")` repeats the string or why `>>= return "Hey"` does the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I understand how `>>= (\_ -> return "Hey")` would yield `["Hey", "Hey", "Hey"]`

right. `return "Hey"` is in this case the same as `["Hey"]`, because

```
instance Monad [] where
  return x = [x]
```

So

```
([1..3] >>= \_ -> return "Hey")
  ≡  ([1..3] >>= \_ -> ["Hey"])
  ≡  ["Hey"] ++ ["Hey"] ++ ["Hey"]
  ≡  ["Hey", "Hey", "Hey"]
```

Now, `>>= (\_ -> "Hey")` can also be be written with a list-result in the lambda, because strings are just lists of characters.

```
([1..3] >>= \_ -> "Hey")
  ≡  ([1..3] >>= \_ -> ['H','e','y'])
  ≡  ['H','e','y'] ++ ['H','e','y'] ++ ['H','e','y']
  ≡  ['H','e','y','H','e','y','H','e','y']
  ≡  "HeyHeyHey"
```

As for `>>= return "Hey"`, that's a different beast. The `return` belongs to a completely different monad here, namely the *function functor*.

```
instance Monad (x->) where
  return y = const y
```

Hence it's kind of clear that `([1..3] >>= const "Hey")` and `([1..3] >>= return "Hey")` give the same result: in that example, `return` is just another name for `const`!

Comment: I was always curious how one could look at any given haskell expression (eg `[1..3] >> return "Hey"`) and know which implementation a particular function (eg `return`) is using – how would I know that the Function Functor's `return` was used in this case ?

Comment: @naomik - looking at the types. From `[1..3]` we know that the left-hand-side of `>>=` is of type `Num a => [a]`, which means that `>>=` is defined in `instance Monad []`, and its right-hand side must be of type `Num a => a -> [b]`. We already knew `return "Hey" :: Monad m => m String`, so now we can state `m String ~ a -> [b]`, which we can have match up if we take `b ~ Char` and `m ~ (->) a`, so `return` must be defined by `instance Monad ((->) a)`.

Comment: @rampion there's a grin on my face as I begin to understand it. I still have two questions tho – 1) how can I precisely interpret `~` in (eg) `m String ~ a -> [b]`? and 2) is it possible that multiple `return` implementations could satisfy the required type?

Comment: 1) `~` is type-level equality. You'll see it in hand-wavy type inference proofs like the one I gave and in type constraints (e.g. `(Show a, Monad m, m a ~ String)`). 2) In this specific example, no, because we narrowed `m` to be `Num a => (->) a` and `instance Monad ((->) a)` doesn't depend on `a`. If there were separate `instance Monad ((->) Int` and `instance Monad ((->) Float)` instead, it'd be a different answer though.  Both would match.

Comment: @rampion thank you for your help – did you ever finish work on [thrill digger assistant](http://rampion.blogspot.ca/2011/12/thrill-digger-and-expected-value.html)? This type of problem is very interesting to me and I'd like to see your work if it's been open sourced ^_^

Answer (score 6):

The `return` being used here is not for the list monad, but for the function monad, in which this definition holds:

```
return x = \_ -> x
```

So this is the same as:

```
[1,2,3] >>= (\_ -> "Hey")
```

and since `(>>=)` is the same as `concatMap` for lists, we have:

```
concatMap (\_ -> "Hey") [1,2,3]
```

Can you see why this yields `"HeyHeyHey"`?